# iOS simulator screen doesn't resize to actual device size even though used scaling in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have recently upgraded Xcode 6.1.1 to 6.4. The simulators in 6.4 has large screen sizes. Even though I used scaling, the simulator become smaller as well as the screen also got small with respect to simulator. I have tried using different scaling sizes (75,50,33,25)% and also performed "Reset content and settings" option of iOS simulators.

Thanks in Advance.